# Change styles of specific column

Tags: angularjs

I have the following declaration of a table with columns that are created dynamically:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td ng-class="{ 'tdhead' : $index == 0 }" 
                   ng-repeat="col in row.cols">{{col.val}}</td>     
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the example the `ng-class` depends on the `row` variable and it changes all the td classes in the first row. But I also need to change the td classes in a specific column. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps just add below condition in your `ng-class`

```
ng-class="{ 'tdhead' : $index == 0 && $parent.$index == 1 }"
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl',
  function MainCtrl($scope) {



    $scope.rows = [{
      name: "abc1",
      empid: 10215,
      cols: ["heading1", "heading2", "heading3"]
    }, {
      name: "abc2",
      empid: 10216,
      cols: ["heading1", "heading2", "heading3"]
    }, {
      name: "abc3",
      empid: 10217,
      cols: ["heading1", "heading2", "heading3"]
    }, {
      name: "abc4",
      empid: 10218,
      cols: ["heading1", "heading2", "heading3"]
    }, {
      name: "abc5",
      empid: 10219,
      cols: ["heading1", "heading2", "heading3"]
    }];




  }
);
```

```css
.tdhead {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
    <td ng-class="{ 'tdhead' : $index == 1 && $parent.$index == 3 }" ng-repeat="col in row.cols">{{col}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In the code snippet I used for 4 row(index 3) 2 column(index 1) you can even make this values dynamic